# Some cck fields not turning into HTML

Tags: drupal-6, cck

I asked [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/13359/some-cck-fields-not-turning-into-html) at drupal.stackexchange as well but response is poor.

My problem happens in my custom Zen-based theme where I made a custom node type 'events'. I put print_r($node) inside of my node-events.tpl.php which gave all the ckk fields including the ones that didn't turn into HTML i.e. not displayed.

When viewing this type of node in a stock drupal theme, this problem doesn't occur so everything gets displayed as desired. This means my viewing permissions are in check and also under admin->content type-> 'events' -> display fields hidden is turned off (set to standard just the way it was when I didn't have the problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all, it was a tpl.php I had overridden for another purpose than this content type that influenced this. So getting rid of that template file in my sites/all/themes/templates folder did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

clear cache.
clear theme cache.

Guess this should help.

Comment: forgot to mention I did that too. 
I'll post the answer in an answer